# EPPLUS - Add custom validation

Tags: c#, epplus

I using EPPlus for exporting excel. I would like add custom validation like this =>[xlsxCustomValidation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcsbp.png) (Sorry in french)
Following is the code

```
ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Feuil1");
var validation = ws.DataValidations.AddCustomValidation("B3");
validation.AllowBlank = true;
validation.Formula.ExcelFormula = "MOD(B3;A3)=0";
```

but I get error on file opening. I tried different way without success.
I managed other validations like Integer but not custom.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Use comma <kbd>,</kbd> instead of semicolon <kbd>;</kbd> for separating function arguments:

```
MOD(B3,A3)=0
```

Excel functions uses system list separator, you can check what kind of separator your system uses in [system settings](https://www.excel-exercise.com/comma-or-semicolon-in-excel-formula/) or programatically:

1. Install NuGet [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/)
2. Get the separator from interop:

```
var listSeparator = new Application().International[XlApplicationInternational.xlListSeparator];
```

Comment: thank you so much, You are right, semicolon was my mistake.